# Uniform measure on an affine variety

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, haar-measure

I'm trying to find an algorithm that uniformly samples elements in the following variety:

$A_p=\{(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n) \in [0,1]^n / \sum \lambda_i = 1, \, \sum \lambda_i^2 = p\}$

I think it can be formalized as finding the Haar measure over $A_p$ (seen as an algebraic group), but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed to come up with the algorithm.

Any idea?

Comment: It isn't a variety. What group law ? And what don't you like in the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The corresponding algorithm needs to find the measure of $A_p \cap \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n , \lambda_j \in [c_j,d_j],j \le m\}$

Comment: @reuns this is contained in a positive-codimension submanifold, so it has Lebesgue measure 0. As for the statement of the original problem, I agree there are several issues - this is not a variety in the typical sense, and I don't see a group law. As for constructive approaches to the problem, if you want to find a measure, one particularly simple way to do that is to pick an $n-2$ form to integrate over this.

Comment: @reuns: my bad then, I haven't studied algebraic geometry properly, I just meant a set defined by polynomial equations (but the restriction to $[0,1]^n$ is probably the issue here).
@ KReiser indeed, the fact that it's measure 0 is my main problem and the reason I can't use a simple Monte Carlo method. I can relax the condition of the sum of the squares (which can be in $[p,p+\epsilon]$), but not the sum equal to 1. In that case, I still need a uniform sampling algorithm over a restricted hyperplane...
Could you develop the idea with the $n-2$-form?

Comment: @reuns You need to explain how you're obtaining the measure on the set the OP is interested in, then - it doesn't seem to me like there's some sort of canonical isomorphism at play here. OP: sure - any continuous differential form $\omega$ on a manifold produces a measure given by assigning to any open set $A$ the number $\int_A |\omega|$. If you can find a particularly suitable form, this will give you a measure. I'd look to exploit the symmetry in the defining equations for your set.

Comment: @KReiser Given $\lambda_3,\ldots,\lambda_{n}, A = \sum_{j=3}^n \lambda_j^2, B = \sum_{j=3}^n \lambda_j$ the equation $A+\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2 = p,B+\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$ gives $A+\lambda_1^2+(1-B-\lambda_1)^2=p$ so it
has zero, one or two solution. So split $[0,1]^2$ in regions where the number of solutions is constant then and weight the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^{n-2}$ accordingly. The resulting algorithm once we know the measure of each region is just : pick a region randomly with the correct probability, then generate randoms points of $[0,1]^{n-2}$ until it is in the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$
B_{n,p}=\{\lambda\mid \textstyle\sum_i \lambda_i=1, \sum_i \lambda_i^2=p\}
$$
You can show that $B_{n,p}$ is an $(n-2)$ dimensional sphere with center $(1/n,1/n,\dots,1/n)$ and radius $\sqrt{p-\tfrac1n}$ in the hyperplane defined by $\sum_i \lambda_i=1$. Therefore, to sample uniformly from $B_{n,p}$, it suffices to use [this method](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24688/efficiently-sampling-points-uniformly-from-the-surface-of-an-n-sphere) to sample a point on the unit hypersphere of dimension $(n-2)$, then apply an appropriate affine transformation.

However, you instead want to sample from
$$
A_{n,p}=B_{n,p}\cap [0,1]^n
$$
You could do this using rejection sampling; sample randomly from $B_{n,p}$, repeating until the point is in $[0,1]^n$. The unfortunate aspect of this is that as $p$ gets closer to its maximum value for which $A_{n,p}$ is nonempty, the probability of a sample lying in the box will go to zero, so the expected number of re-samples will approach infinity. However, this will work well for moderate values of $p$.